# How do you remove the Xubuntu 11 toolbar at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: xubuntu

I want to replace it with a toolbar that resembles the Mac OS...can't remember what it is called but it has nice effects.

Comment: It's called a Dock, a Toolbar is where the Application's Action controls are, Back Forward, Home, Refresh, those Tools. A dock acts as Launcher and a Window navigator in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are referring to the Panel at the bottom of the screen. Like all panels - you can just remove this panel and then add whatever dock you which to use.

[image]

Right click the second panel and choose *Panel Preferences* - you can then delete the Panel as shown.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The dock you want is probably Docky. Start the software centre and search for Docky, or start a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install docky`.

You can install Avant Window Navigator, but I suggest you don't. Unfortunately it isn't very well packaged for Xubuntu, and brings in an enormous amount of the unity and gnome desktop packages from 'vanilla' Ubuntu, which are then really hard to get rid of. I know, I tried.

Comment: It does because it has packages that depend on gnome. Docky doesn't also there's Plank nice overly simplistic dock.